# Additivity of suprema

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I'm currently starting with a more formal approach of calculus. I am reading Apostol's Calculus Vol. 1 and found the proof of the additivity of suprema confusing. Could someone please do it and explain it without skipping any steps.

The conditions given in the book are:

Let A and B be nonempty sets that have a supremum.
Given that
$$
C=\{a+b | a\in A, b\in B\}
$$
Prove that:
$$
\sup C=\sup A +\sup B
$$

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $a+b\leqslant\sup A+\sup B$ and therefore $\sup A+\sup B$ is an upper bound of $C$. So, $\sup C\leqslant\sup A+\sup B$.

Now, suppose that $\sup C<\sup A+\sup B$. Take $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $\sup C<a+b\leqslant\sup A+\sup B$. But $a+b\in C$ and so we can't have $a+b>\sup C$.

Can you finish the proof by proving that *if* $\sup C<\sup A+\sup B$, *then* there must be an $a\in A$ and a $b\in B$ such that $\sup C<a+b$?